# Removing list elements with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

A blog I read has some annoying commenters.  I thought I would try my hand at Greasemonkey to turn them off.

The basic structure of the HTML is simple - a comment looks something like this:

```
<li>
  <cite>user name ...</cite>
  comment text
</li>
```

So with that in mind, I bashed my head against the keyboard for a while until this dropped out:

```
var killlist = /user1|user2/;

var comments = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

if (comments.length) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < comments.length; i ++ ) {
    var comment = comments[i];
    var cites = comment.getElementsByTagName('cite');
    if (cites.length) {
      var cite = cites[0];
      var title = cite.textContent;
      if (killlist.test(title)) {
        comment.parentNode.removeChild(comment);
      }
    }
  }
}

window.alert('Done!')
```

(the `window.alert` is just so I know if the script runs to completion)

This *mostly* works.  e.g. on one test page, it removed 13 of 16 posts by one of the users.  I tried replacing the removeChild line with this:

```
comment.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

That appears to get everything, but at the expense of leaving great empty spaces where the comments would have been.

I'm a complete javascript newbie, so can anyone see anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to fix it by reversing the order of your for loop and deleting elements from the end of the comments array first:

```
for ( var i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
```

Comment: I wondered if that might be a problem, so I tried making an array to comments to delete, and then deleting frrom it, but to no avail.  But this is looking promising so far!  I will test for a little longer and then come back.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you're seeing is due to `comments` being a [live `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName). As you remove elements referenced by `comments` from the DOM, `comments` is mutated (and its `length` updated) and your loop goes out the window.

You can loop in reverse order as @Pat suggested, or "unhook" the `NodeList` from the DOM with a copy operation first:

```
var comments = Array.slice(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

Then proceed as before.